# Removing Strikethrough text and copying to a new column is missing the first dot

Tags: excel, vba, strikethrough

Hi I am using this code to remove any text in a cell that is striked through and copying it to a new column cell.. Its removing the strike through text but when copying the text to a new cell it misses the first dot after the 1. i.e

```
1.0900 - 1800     its copying as   10900 - 1800
2.0830 - 1700                      2.0830 - 1700
```

---

```
For Each cel In rng
For i = 1 To Len(cel.Value)
If cel.Characters(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough = False Then
cel.Offset(0, -1).Value = cel.Offset(0, -1).Value & cel.Characters(i, 1).Text

End If
Next
```

Any idea why its missing the dot?  It only does it on the first line on each cell.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you write one character after another and if you write `1.` into a cell it gets reduced to `1` automatically.

```
For Each cel In rng
    Dim OutputText As String
    OutputText = vbNullString 'initialize

    For i = 1 To Len(cel.Value)
        If cel.Characters(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough = False Then
            OutputText = OutputText & cel.Characters(i, 1).Text
        End If
    Next i

    cel.Offset(0, -1).Value = OutputText
Next cel
```

So put all the characters together in a variable and write all at once in the end is even much faster.